# woocommerce - product images are not even on category page

Tags: image, woocommerce, product

I am doing a furniture website in woocommerce and my images dont want to line u on the category pages.  So the couch is up top and the chair is the full height -  I just want it in a nice grid not one up and one down and so on.  Any way to fix this?

Screenshot: [image: products not evenly lined up on woocommerce page]

Comment: This is impossible to answer without seeing code, seeing the live site, and/or seeing screenshots.

Comment: added a screen shot ; )